# Value of one field in one entity has been changed after hibernate call saveOrUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, insert-update

One object has been sent to hibernate saveOrUpdate method for updating the data. Before save the value of one field was different and after save the value in the object got changed. Is this one of the issue of hibernate call? Or it happened due to collision with any other flow because the method hibernate saveOrUpdate is getting called from more than 10 places.

Still trying to find the root cause.

Comment: Just set a breakpoint to the problem field setter and inspect it with a debugger.